# Set attributes on option in ember select

Tags: ember.js

If I have a custom ember select (or any ember select) like:

```
App.SelectGender = Ember.Select.extend
  content: ['Gender', 'Male', 'Female']
```

And I want to set attributes on the first option like:

```
<option value="false" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Gender</option>
```

How can I go about doing that? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: basically you want 'Gender' to be a label?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#toc_supplying-a-prompt is what i think you need

Comment: Thanks @CodeJack. I solved the problem using that. If you want to add that as an answer I will mark it so you get all the cool points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since understandably you wanted to add a prompt label for your Select component you can pass it as a property to Ember.Select like below.

```
{{view Ember.Select
       content=sexArray
       value=SelectedSex
       prompt="Gender"
}}
```

Docs link for same http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#toc_supplying-a-prompt